# convert document file into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, file, fetch

I am working on a ReactJS project and in that, I have to fetch (by JS fetch API) a document (.docx/.doc) file from the server and convert it into JSON. After some research, I got to know that document files are unstructured that's why we can't convert them into JSON. So my question is.

-Is it true that document files could not be converted into JSON by JS?

I used the below code but it's not working. The same code is working with excel files.

```
 fetch("url/container/file.docx").then(res => {
        return res.arrayBuffer()
    }).then(result => {
        const _Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(result);
         //for xlsx here i am using xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json
        console.log(_Uint8Array);
    })
```

I found the same questions on the internet but I didn't get any proper solution to my issue.

Comment: Can you show the content inside the document file?

Comment: @Tân I am sharing a sample file screenshot. https://ibb.co/w4xHVcC

Comment: Nope. You cannot convert the content inside the document to a json object because it's not a valid json format. But if you want to convert it to `{ content: "..." }`, there are some ways.

Comment: docx2json.com is a react app that displays the contents of the docx file as JSON.  It works by passing the docx file to a python server (aiohttp) which uses the  [simplify-docx](https://github.com/microsoft/Simplify-Docx) python library to convert the docx to file to JSON. While I don't know of a JS library with the same functionality, passing data  to a server with additional capabilities is a standard trick that a good developer has in their back pocket.